# Magic trackpad pairing issues with Lion

Tags: bluetooth, magic-trackpad

**The Question**
How can I unpair the trackpad as a mouse and pair it using trackpad option instead?

**Background**

I made the mistake of pairing the Magic trackpad via System->Bluetooth->Bluetooth Setup Assistant.  By doing this the only thing I can use the trackpad for is pointing an left clicking.  I now see that it can be paired via the System->Trackpad->Set Up Bluetooth Trackpad... option.

**What I have tried**

Inside Bluetooth settings: Disconnected the device, then using the `-` button removed it.  Then powered down the trackpad and restarted the pairing process by holding the power button.

While the green led is flashing, I go to the Trackpad set up and find the device.  However it keeps failing when connecting to the trackpad.  I did notice that it fails immediately  after seeing the "Connected" message displayed on my screen.  At this point I can use the trackpad as a pointing device, but am unable to connect to it using the trackpad set up.

**System Settings**
OS X Lion
Using USB Overdrive (for a wired logitech mouse)

**UPDATE**
Following the advice of a comment, I used the XCode's Bluetooth Manger and reset every possible device.  The issue still persists.

To find the Bluetooth Manger (assuming you have XCode installed and using Finder): Browse to `MacHD/Developer/Applications/Utilities/Bluetooth`

Comment: Have you isolated this to Lion (by pairing successfully with Snow Leopard) or is that just some of the background in hopes it helps? The free Xcode has both a Bluetooth Explorer and a Bluetooth Diagnostic Utility that may help you suss this out.

Comment: @bmike: I dont have SL infront of me now.  I have it home (which I will try later).  Giving Xcode a shot now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was USB Overdrive.  Running 3.1 still causes issues with Lion.

When Overdrive is installed it only sees the trackpad as a mouse.  I uninstalled USB Overdrive and Lion detected it after reboot with no trouble at all.

[This](http://www.maclife.com/article/howtos/how_successfully_pair_your_magic_trackpad_your_mac) link was quite helpful as well.

Comment: Be sure to click the checkmark next to your answer; it's totally fine to accept your own answer and will help others in the future. And good thing you figured it out since I added my trackpad  via the Bluetooth Setup Assistant and it works great.

Comment: I am unable to accept it for 2 more days. :)

Comment: Ah. :) Just wanted to make sure you knew that you could.

Answer (score 1):

Did you unpair by going to `System Preferences...` ->   `Trackpad` -> `Set Up Bluetooth Trackpad...`

Then select the trackpad and choose `Unpair`
This is different to just removing it from the list of Bluetooth devices.
You will then be able to pair it again properly.

[image: Bluetooth pairing dialogue]

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The trackpad's Set Up Bluetooth Trackpad option was never able to connect to it.  Each time it tried, it was paired as mouse instead and killed the Trackpad Menu's attempt.

Comment: @Adam Did you try un-pairing it from the mouse preferences? I don't have a mouse so don't know what that looks like. This is different to removing it from the Bluetooth device list described in your question.

Comment: @AdamLewis Also, if this is an iMac, or not a laptop, do you have a usb mouse you can use to un-pair and re-pair? You may need that. see http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2845

Comment: I did not try to un-pair it from the mouse preferences...  Good thought though.  I am using a Macbook Pro (with a USB mouse  and now + Magic Trackpad). By using Xcode I am fairly sure that I blew away all pairing (I explicitly checked this).  When I have a bit more time, I will re-install USB Overdrive and see if your comments work.